# How to get Vue3 Object single element?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, object, element, vuejs3

When I try to add `courseDatas.title` in v-for I get error: courseDatas is null

**App.vue**

```
<template>
<div v-for="(courseDatas, index) in courseDatas" :key="index">
{{ index }} - {{ courseDatas }}
</div>
```

```
<script>
export default {
data() {
return {
  courseDatas: JSON.parse(
    document.getElementById("app").getAttribute("course")
   ),
  };
 },
};
```

**Result**
[image]

When I add this:

```
<template>
<div v-for="(courseDatas, index) in courseDatas" :key="index">
{{ index }} - {{ courseDatas }} {{ courseDatas.title }}
</div>
```

[image]

**EDIT**
**index.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    @foreach ($course as $courses)
    <div id="app" course="{{$courses}}">
        
    </div>
    @endforeach
    <script src="{{asset('js/course/app.js')}}"></script>
@endsection
```

Comment: your getting data from html ?

Comment: From laravel blade, but it same.

Comment: but why ? vuejs need to use api to get data not blade

Comment: Don't define the local value in the loop `courseDatas` the same as the list variable

Answer (score 1):

check if the property is not null then render it using `v-for` and name the current item `course`

```
<template>
  <template v-if="courseDatas">
   <div v-for="(course, index) in courseDatas" :key="index">
    {{ index }} - {{ course}}
   </div>
  <template>
<template>
```

and avoid to manipulate DOM as you did, define a prop called `course` as follows :

```
<script>
export default {
props:["course"],
data() {
return {
  courseDatas: this.course
  };
 },
};
```

Comment: I get data from laravel blade, so I cant use props.

Comment: how do you get that data please show the code of your blade

Comment: You should define a component then pass `course` prop to it

Comment: what did you try out?

Comment: Define a component and then pass course prop.